# Do you say certificate about or certificate of?

Tags: prepositions

Do you say certificate about or certificate of?

"Additional certificate **about** grading system."

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what do you want your sentence to mean? I don't understand the meaning of "certificate about/of grading system". What or who is being certified?

Comment: This certificate explains the difference between 20 pt scale(0-20) and 4pt scale(0-4).

Comment: Irrespecitve of what that certificate is, good question! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!

I won't get into the nuance of what that certificate is all about. I'd address the question in the title -do you say certificate 'about' or 'of'.

Though both convey the same meaning, in my opinion, **in most of the cases,** when you say *'certificate about...'* it takes a phrase. I mean to say that there could be some explanation of what that certificate is all about, and **not just one word**.

For instance `a doctor's certificate about the applicant's fitness for the job`

On the other hand, *'certificate of'* is short and terse. It directly says what is that certificate with no explanation.

Say - `a certificate of registration/membership/excellence/participation...and so on`

But I repeat, both conveys the same meaning and there's no *strict rule* about what I said. It's just my minute observation.

Comment: Thanks  I got this certificate from ministry of science http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_Iran